# blogs of David Sklansky

Tags: books

I used to read Sklansky's blogs on 2+2, and he put some of those articles into books like eg 'poker, gaming, and life' and 'DUCY'. I really enjoyed it. But that was 10 years ago.

Does David Sklansky still write poker blogs or share his random thoughts? Where can I find it?

Comment: Maybe ask over at 2+2. David's son was and likely is still a moderator there. Mason is still active. Someone should be able to point the way if there is  a way, However if there not linking to new stuff from Sklansky, I would say there is no new stuff. Sklansky is in his seventies and he might not be doing much writing anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked Mason Malmuth he said David has never done a blog. He is however still active at 2+2.